# Passing form variables from one page to another

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have an existing app http://www.successcalculator.com. Currently, it functions all on one page but I have been asked to change it to a multipage flow. I am having trouble passing data from one page to the next. I'm more of a hobbyist developer so programming is not my forte.

**Here's a sample of the HTML code:**

```html
<form>

<output id="averageJobsOut">30</output>
<input type="range" id="averageJobs" value="30" min="0" max="100" step="5" oninput="averageJobsOut.value = averageJobs.value" required>


<output id="jobValueOut">30</output>
<input type="range" id="jobValue" value="30" min="50" max="2000" step="10" oninput="jobValueOut.value = jobValue.value" required>

<output id="yearsOpenOut">3</output>
<input type="range" id="yearsOpen" value="3" min="1" max="20" step="1" oninput="yearsOpenOut.value = yearsOpen.value" required>

<input type="submit" onSubmit="calculateAll()"></input>

</form>
```

**Here is a sample of the JavaScript:**

```js
function calculateAll() {

 var averageJobs = +document.getElementById("averageJobs").value;
 var jobValue = +document.getElementById("jobValue").value;
  
  var yearlyRev = parseInt((averageJobs * 50) * jobValue);
  
  document.getElementById("yearlyRev").value = yearlyRev + " Yearly Revenue";
  
  }
```

I would like the app to gather peoples input as it does now and on submission of the form I would like it to redirect people to results.html where the form results would be available.

I have adding the following JavaScript to the calculateAll() function but can't seem to get the data to move over. I also tried some basic PHP GET & POST functions in the form but could only bring over form input not the calculations.

```js
var averageJobs = document.getElementById("averageJobs").innerHTML;
localStorage.setItem("averageJobs", averageJobs); 
window.open("results.html","_self");
```

Any assistance or insight would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are many ways to do this, I would go with one of the easier solutions, ditch the JS function, directly send your form to a php file, do your calculations there and print them in that same file.

Comment: Or even better you can ditch sending your form to PHP, by sending data to PHP using `AJAX`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Lixus. So my understanding is that I would have to add action="example.php" to the form tag and then just re-write my calculations in PHP then. Would this same file also handle the redirect to results.html?

Comment: @julekgwa any good resources you could point me to on ajax basics? I'll explore both the php file and ajax options.

Comment: It would be more like results will go from results.html to results.php so you can in that same file print your results without going to yet another file.

Comment: with ajax you are still going to work in the same file, but the data will be sent to php, I think that's not what you want, but if applied correctly it might work.

Answer (score 0):

30



30


3

Use form action with php, instead of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Use form method to pass data and catch them via a php page. You can use POST to hide data and GET to show data that you are passing via url. For this POST is preferrable.

```
<form action="action_page.php" method="POST">
```

from the php file you can catch the data by creating your own variables and using this

```
$var1 = $_POST('Name_of_the_Controller');
```